# Python - how to recursively search a variable substring in texts that are elements of a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion, search, substring

let me explain better what I mean in the title.
Examples of strings where to search (i.e. strings of variable lengths
each one is an element of a list; very large in reality):

```py
STRINGS = ['sftrkpilotndkpilotllptptpyrh', 'ffftapilotdfmmmbtyrtdll', 'gftttepncvjspwqbbqbthpilotou', 'htfrpilotrtubbbfelnxcdcz']
```

The substring to find, which I know is for sure:

- contained in each element of `STRINGS`
- is also contained in a `SOURCE` string
- is of a certain fixed `LENGTH` (5 characters in this example).

```py
SOURCE = ['gfrtewwxadasvpbepilotzxxndffc']
```

I am trying to write a Python3 program that finds this hidden **word** of 5 characters that is in `SOURCE` and at what position(s) it occurs in each element of `STRINGS`.

I am also trying to store the results in an array or a dictionary (I do not know what is more convenient at the moment).

Moreover, I need to perform other searches of the same type but with different `LENGTH` values, so this value should be provided by a variable in order to be of more general use.

I know that the ***first*** point has been already solved in previous posts, but
never (as far as I know) together with the ***second*** point, which is the part of the code I could not be able to deal with successfully (I do not post my code because I know it is just too far from being fixable).

Any help from this great community is highly appreciated.

-- Maurizio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the source string and for each sub-string use the `re` module to find the positions within each of the other strings. Then if at least one occurrence was found for each of the strings, yield the result:

```
import re

def find(source, strings, length):
    for i in range(len(source) - length):
        sub = source[i:i+length]
        positions = {}
        for s in strings:
            # positions[s] = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(re.escape(sub), s)]
            positions[s] = [i for i in range(len(s)) if s.startswith(sub, i)]  # Using built-in functions.
            if not positions[s]:
                break
        else:
            yield sub, positions
```

And the generator can be used as illustrated in the following example:

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(dict(find(
    source='gfrtewwxadasvpbepilotzxxndffc',
    strings=['sftrkpilotndkpilotllptptpyrh',
             'ffftapilotdfmmmbtyrtdll',
             'gftttepncvjspwqbbqbthpilotou',
             'htfrpilotrtubbbfelnxcdcz'],
    length=5
)))
```

which produces the following output:

```
{'pilot': {'ffftapilotdfmmmbtyrtdll': [5],
           'gftttepncvjspwqbbqbthpilotou': [21],
           'htfrpilotrtubbbfelnxcdcz': [4],
           'sftrkpilotndkpilotllptptpyrh': [5, 13]}}
```

Comment: Not that it is covered by the question, and the answer is amazing, but this wouldn't cover a wrap around correct? (Ex: `lotabcdpi` -> `pilot` wraps around). That would complicate things :P

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the code should be made of built-in commands only, i..e. import of extra mofules not allowed.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse In that case you could use `s += s[:length-1]` prior to matching the sub-string (or rather match against `s + s[:length-1]`).

Comment: @a_guest I accepted your solution. Two more points: could you kindly explain what the lines of your code do, particularly the inner for loop when defining the function find is not clear to me. Also, you defined the source variable as a string while I wrote that it should be a string as a single element of a list. Although it is easy to make a conversion from list to string I wonder how the code would change. Anyway, thanks for your support.

Comment: @MaurizioCirilli The inner `for` loop checks for each test string at which positions the sub string of length `length` is contained. In case there is a test string which doesn't contain the sub string, it `break`s out of the loop since the requirement is not met. The `else` clause at the end of the `for` loop is only entered if the loop was not terminated via `break`, i.e. only if it terminated normally. Only then all test strings met the condition and the result is `yield`ed. To change from list to string you can simply use `source = source[0]`.